# PHP Wildcard in Variable

Tags: php, wildcard

I am working on a PHP script which will read a METAR weather report and let me know if it is raining or not.  The possible precipitation is reported as:

```
DZ, GR, GS, IC, PL, RA, SG, SN, and UP
```

The problem is sometimes these are combined and can also have a + or - in front so these can happen:

```
+RA
-RA
RASN
DZIC
etc.
```

Is there a way to setup a wildcard to the right and left of the two letter variables to accomidate these possibilities?

```
$metar = "2013/12/30 00:51 KALB 300051Z 33006KT 1 1/2SM -SN BR BKN004 OVC022 01/M01 A2961 RMK AO2 SFC VIS 2 RAE2354 SLP030 P0010 T00061006 $";
if ($metar == *DZ* || $metar == *GR* || $metar == *GS* || $metar == *IC* || $metar == *PL* || $metar == *RA* || $metar == *SG* || $metar == *SN* || $metar == *UP*) {
$rain == "Rain";
} else $rain == "No Rain";
```

Comment: isn't that what regular expressions are for?

Comment: Are `+` and `-` significant or do you just want to ignore them?

Comment: I am still learning PHP. + and - are used so I would have to answer yes they are important.

Comment: I corrected the $metar to what it actually is.

Comment: I would like to be able to view the full result found if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression match will find all combinations of letter pairs, with an optional preceding `+` or `-` character.

```
// The string of weather codes
$theString = '+RA -RA RASN DZIC';

// This regex matches all combination of letter pairs with an
// optional preceding + or -
$regex = '/(?<=^|\s)[+-]?(?:DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP)+(?=$|\s)/';

// Find as many matches as there are in the string
preg_match_all($regex, $theString, $matches);
$weatherCodes = array_shift($matches);

// Output the weather codes
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($weatherCodes);
echo '</pre>';
```

It will output something like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '+RA' (length=3)
  1 => string '-RA' (length=3)
  2 => string 'RASN' (length=4)
  3 => string 'DZIC' (length=4)
```

If you want the weather code combinations in a more useful data format then you can use a function like this to parse them out.

```
function getWeatherCodes($codes) {
    $regex = '/(?<=^|\s)[+-]?(?:DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP)+(?=$|\s)/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $codes, $matches);
    $matches = array_shift($matches);
    foreach ($matches as & $match) {
        $newItem = array('sign'=>null, 'codes'=>array());
        if (strlen($match) % 2 != 0) {
            $newItem['sign'] = $match[0];
            $match = substr($match, 1);
        }
        $newItem['codes'] = str_split($match, 2);
        $match = $newItem;
    }
    return $matches;
}
$theString = 'RA +DZIC';
$weatherCodes = getWeatherCodes($theString);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($weatherCodes);
echo '</pre>';
```

Which will output something like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'sign' => null
      'codes' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'RA' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'sign' => string '+' (length=1)
      'codes' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'DZ' (length=2)
          1 => string 'IC' (length=2)
```

Comment: I am still a complete PHP noob.  Is there a way to use this to search the entire METAR report for the possibility of the precipitation code and combination used, set $rain to "Rain" if found, and display the result via echo?  Here is the full METAR which has -SN in it: 2013/12/30 01:51 KALB 300151Z 32004KT 1 1/2SM -SN BR SCT004 OVC019 01/M01 A2962 RMK AO2 SFC VIS 2 SLP033 SCT V BKN P0008 T00061006 $

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Unlike other answers, this uses `preg_match_all` to match all items in the `$metar` string. So `RA` and `SN` are matched as well. I have put all of the codes into an array to make it easier to add/remove items:

```
// Test data.
// $metar = "+RA -RA RASN DZIC";
$metar = "-RASN";

// Codes placed in an array.
$codes = array('DZ','GR','GS','IC','PL','RA','SG','SN','UP');

// Using a 'preg_match_all' as well as 'implode' to compare all items in the array to the test data.
preg_match_all('/' . implode('|', $codes) . '/is', $metar, $matches);

// Check the count of '$matches[0]' to see if any matches are made or not.
if (count($matches[0]) > 0) {
  $rain = "Rain";
}
else {
  $rain = "No Rain";
}

// Echo the results.
echo $rain;
```

You can debug with this to see the output of `$matches`:

```
// Dump the '$matches' for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output using my example is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => RA
            [1] => SN
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$metar = "-RASN";
if (preg_match('/DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP/', $metar)) {
    $rain = "Rain";
} else {
    $rain = "No Rain";
}
```

If it always starts with "+" or "-" or not, you can do this :

```
if (preg_match('/^(\+|-)?(DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP)/', $metar)) {
    $rain = "Rain";
} else {
    $rain = "No Rain";
}
```

See http://php.net/preg_match for more details.

If you need to print the matches, you should do something like :

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\+|-)?(DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP)/', $metar, $matches)) {
    echo 'Rain (matching codes: ' . implode(', ', $matches[0]) . ')';
} else {
    echo "No Rain";
}
```

Comment: I just seen and corrected it. It was just copy/paste from question.

Comment: preg_match returns 1, so $rain is set to "Rain". That's all I need.

Comment: I am still a complete noob to PHP.  Is there a way to echo out the preg_match result found?

Comment: $metar can be a long line like this: 2013/12/30 01:51 KALB 300151Z 32004KT 1 1/2SM -SN BR SCT004 OVC019 01/M01 A2962 RMK AO2 SFC VIS 2 SLP033 SCT V BKN P0008 T00061006 $ so it would be cool if there was a way to match to -SN if it is there (it is) and display the match via echo.

Comment: In this case, you should do this :
if (preg_match_all('/DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP/', $metar, $matches)) { $rain='Rain'; echo implode(', ', $matches[0]);}

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
<?php
    $metar = "-RASN";
    if (preg_match("/[+-]?(DZ|GR|GS|IC|PL|RA|SG|SN|UP)/", $metar)) {
       $rain = "Rain";
    }
    else {
       $rain = "No Rain";
    }
?>
```

Please note that it must be `$rain = "Rain"` ie *one* `=` which means assignment. `==` is for comparison.

Comment: Assuming the OP means that any of the two character symbols regardless of prefix +- should trigger "Rain", why bother with the "other half"? In fact, `[+-]?` could also be removed to simplify. Else, the original question is not clear.

Comment: I tried to clear it up some more.  I need to search the entire METAR for the possibility and combination of the precipitation codes.  If a match is found, I need $rain = "Rain"; and I need a way to display the match found via echo.